# MySQL and PHP -- too many entries?? newsletter thing

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, email, doctrine

So I'm trying to send a newsletter to about 2560 emails.
The php script creates an entry for each e-mail in a table and every 15 minutes , 50 mails are sent so the server doesn't get busy.

The problem is , when I try to send the newsletter to all 2560 emails , I get a 404 page and when I only select my Email , everything goes as it should. I'm thinking there is some limit that prevents the mysql to add that many entries , that fast .

Any way to fix that?

part of code:

```
   $conn =  sfContext::getInstance()->getDatabaseManager()->getDatabase('doctrine')->getDoctrineConnection(); 

    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
    set_time_limit(0);
    try 
    { 

    $conn->beginTransaction();

    foreach ($to as $email => $name)
    {
      if (is_integer($email))
      {
        $email = $name;
      }

      $hash = substr(md5($email), 0, 5);

      //save to cron job

      $html = str_replace(array('[+hash+]', '[+email+]'),array($hash, $email), $content);

      $query = $conn->prepare($sql = "INSERT INTO CronEmail (sendto_name, sendto_email, from_name, from_email, subject, message, created_at)
       VALUES (:sendto_name, :sendto_email, :from_name, :from_email, :subject, :message, :created_at);");


      $query->execute(
        array('sendto_name' => $name,
            'sendto_email' => $email,
            'from_name' => "Newsletter " . $fromsite,
            'from_email' =>  "newsletter@office.ro",
            'subject' => $newsletter->getSubject(),
            'message' => $html,
           'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
       );

    }

    $conn->commit();

    }catch (Doctrine_Exception $e) { // Rollback if transaction fail 
      $conn->rollback(); 
      echo $sql;  
      echo $e->getMessage();
      die();
    }


    $this->getUser()->setFlash('alert', '<div class="alert_ok">Newsletterul a fost salvat si va fi trimis!</div>');

    $this->redirect('newsletter_send/index');
  }
}
```

Comment: The is no limit in MySQL. I _could_ imagine that you hit some php limit, certainly. I suggest you start looking into your http servers error log file which is where you can simply _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: I would look into the array of email recipients - any syntax error in there could cause an error. mysql has no limit and you give your php plenty of air with memory and time limits

Comment: This does not seem related to the code, a 404 means "page not found". If it were a 5xx error, the problem would probably be with the code. Assuming an http error of course. What is the exact error message?

Comment: @JohnMas are you using any specific PHP framework for this?

Comment: using an old simfony version 1.4 I believe. Also , uppercase and all that doesn't matter , I tried sending emails to them and it worked.